# if statement for three checkboxes javascript

Tags: javascript

I have recently started javascript at college and am having a little trouble. I am not Including my code here as i dont want it written for me i just need some pointing in the right direction.

So, I have three checkboxes, each with a different value and i need to add together the values for the selected boxes. I understand how to do this but the way im doing it seems a bit long winded and im sure there is a better way.

Currently i have an if statement checking if box1 box2 and box3 are selected, if they are then they are added, else if box 1 and box2 are selected they are added, else if box1 and box2 are selected they are added and so on.

so basically im checking every combination of what boxes can be selected, one at a time. There must be a more efficient way of achieving this so any tips would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: have you asked your TA?

Comment: Code would be helpful, though I think in this case it is not required.  You can just use the values of selected elements if needed, no if required.

Comment: You're asking for a code review, nothing wrong with that. Try over here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, since here we're a little more into solving code problems.

Comment: what do you mean by "added"?

Comment: pure js or jquery is ok?

Comment: what do you mean with different values, a checkbox is either checked or unchecked

Comment: hmm using the values of selected elements sounds like what i need. That is exactly the kind of tip i was looking for. Not too sure how i will make it work yet but il have a fiddle and see what i can come up with.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your HTML resembles the following:

```
<input name="demo" type="checkbox" checked value="1" />
<input name="demo" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input name="demo" type="checkbox" checked value="3" />
```

Then simply retrieve the elements of the relevant name, then iterate through the collection/nodeList and add the values to a declared 'total' variable:

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByName('demo'),
    total = 0;

for (var i = 0, len = boxes.length; i < len; i++){
    if (boxes[i].checked && boxes[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'checkbox') {
        total += parseInt(boxes[i].value, 10);
    }
}

console.log(total);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YtArx/).

the above code is, I think, cross browser compatible; but if you're looking for a more up-to-date technique that simplifies the `for` loop (to omit the `if` checks), then you can use `document.querySelectorAll()` as the selector technique:

```
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="demo"][type="checkbox"]:checked'),
    total = 0;

for (var i = 0, len = boxes.length; i < len; i++){
    total += parseInt(boxes[i].value, 10);
}

console.log(total);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YtArx/1/).

References:

- [`document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDocument.querySelectorAll).
- [`String.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Not bad, would recommend querySelectorAll so that you don't have to use the type check. If he's in college he probably should learn the latest techniques.

Comment: Agreed, I was editing that in (after reviewing a suggested edit which slowed me down a moment or two).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `+=` and a simple ternary operator:

```
var total = 0;
total += document.getElementById('cb1').checked ? parseInt(document.getElementById('cb1').value, 10) : 0;
total += document.getElementById('cb2').checked ? parseInt(document.getElementById('cb2').value, 10) : 0;
total += document.getElementById('cb3').checked ? parseInt(document.getElementById('cb3').value, 10) : 0;
alert(total);
```

I should disclose that is the same as:

```
var total2 = 0;
if (document.getElementById('cb1').checked) total2 += parseInt(document.getElementById('cb1').value, 10);
if (document.getElementById('cb2').checked) total2 += parseInt(document.getElementById('cb2').value, 10);
if (document.getElementById('cb3').checked) total2 += parseInt(document.getElementById('cb3').value, 10);
alert(total2);
```

Examples HTML:

```
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox" value="341" checked />
<input id="cb2" type="checkbox" value="242" />
<input id="cb3" type="checkbox" value="345" checked  />
```